# Como cambiar la codificación de Rmarkdown "must be encoded in UTF-8"?

Tags: r, codificación, r-markdown

Al realizar un archivo html en `Rmarkdown` en los chunks, las palabras que tienen tildes las codifica con otro tipo de codificación distinto al `UTF-8`.

Como se muestra en la siguiente imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Incluso cambie la codificación, como muestro a continuación:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero no he podido solucionar el problema. Espero puedan ayudarme.

**Muchas gracias de antemano**

Comment: En el código fuente, el archivo Rmd, ¿la codificación se ve correcta?

Comment: Haz probado desde Rstudio ir a File -> Save with encoding (Y seleccionar UTF-8)?

Comment: Probé, pero sigue igual. No sé a que se deba. Antes funcionaba bien. Gracias Patricio.